# Is there any difference between rig veda and rig ved samhita

Tags: rig-veda, samhita

Is there any difference between rig veda and rig ved samhita.
Can you explain the difference and what is samhita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Veda is broadly divided into a few parts.

- **Samhita**: liturgy and ritual
- **Brahmanas**: Instruction and context on ritual
- **Aranyakas**: Philosophical commentary on ritual
- **Upanishads**: Philosophy and spirituality

These are loose definitions and don't apply neatly, but broadly speaking, rig veda samhita is the liturgical part of the broader rig veda.